# Webdriver: what is the right way to write a user defined function

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing a login function, I want this function to exit gracefully in case of an error/unexpected condition.example: when I enter the password, if the text field has changed/not present I want the function to exit with the message saying that password field is not present. the function status should be "Fail" and the exact failure message. same way it should handle any other exception that might occur. What is the right way to right this function, so that I can follow this practice in the future functions that I write that deals with web objects?

```
public boolean Login(String userName, String password, String url)
    {


        _driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        _driver.manage().window().maximize();
        _driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
        _driver.get(url);
        _driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[id='usename']")).sendKeys(userName);
        _driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[id='pword']")).sendKeys(password);
        _driver.findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[id='btn']")).click();
        String title = _driver.getTitle();
         boolean pass;
        if (title.toLowerCase().contains("homepage"))
        {
            pass=true;
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.fail("Manager home page not opened after login");
            pass=false;

        }
        return pass;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to remove the driver setup and navigating to the initial URL from your function. Your function should *only* log in... to match the name, `Login()`. If you want to use the page object model, you would do something like

The main script would look like

```
_driver = new FirefoxDriver();
_driver.manage().window().maximize();
_driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
_driver.get(url);
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(_driver);
loginPage.Login(userName, password);
Assert.assertTrue(_driver.getTitle().contains("homepage"), "Log in successful");
```

While the LoginPage class would look like

```
public class LoginPage
{
    WebDriver _driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public void Login(String userName, String password)
    {
        _driver.findElement(By.id("usename")).sendKeys(userName);
        _driver.findElement(By.id("pword]")).sendKeys(password);
        _driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
    }
}
```

BTW, I changed your locators to use `By.id()` instead of XPath. You should avoid using XPath unless it's absolutely necessary... finding an element by containing text, etc. Start with `By.id()` then use `By.cssSelector()`... if those two won't work, then fall back to XPath. XPath is slower, more likely to be brittle, and has inconsistent support in browsers.

Comment: thank you so much.Should i be using a try catch block in the function Login? to catch NoSuchElementException? is it a good practice or unnecessary?

Comment: It really depends on how you have your scripts set up. What are you planning to do if you catch an exception? Can you recover from it? If so, then you may want to catch it. If you can't recover from it then the only thing catching an exception might do is to print a more understandable message. I generally don't catch many exceptions but it really depends.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I plan on printing a more understandable message with it. I have up voted(i am new to stackoverflow, so it dosen't show up. Dont have enough reputation).